# Does numpy broadcast in *all* of its functions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have two objects `X`, `Y` of shape `k,1,n` and `k,m,n`. I know that numpy will automatically extend/repeat `X` along the first dimension when I do operations such as `X + Y`. Does this magic work for all mathematical operations that are supported/included in numpy?

For example, can I do `scipy.special.binom(X,Y)` and get the expected result? I have tried some of the special functions, and I don't receive an error. Does not receiving an error allow me to conclude that the broadcasting was done correctly?

Comment: Is broadcast the right word here?

Comment: @Pureferret I believe it is: "*The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations.*" - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: All binary [ufuncs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) support broadcasting. `binom` is a ufunc and so should work in the same way.

Answer (score 6):

`numpy` does apply broadcasting for all operators, eg. *+-/ etc.  It also applies it where possible to `ufunc` functions.  That's part of the `ufunc` definition.

`scipy.special.binom` is, according to its docs a `ufunc`.  It is compiled so I can't look at the code to verify this, but I can do a few simple tests:

```
In [379]: special.binom([1,2,3],[[1],[2]])
Out[379]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.]])

In [380]: special.binom([1,2,3,4],[[1],[2]])
Out[380]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.,  6.]])

In [385]: special.binom(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2,1),np.arange(6).reshape(3,1,2)).shape
Out[385]: (3, 2, 2)
```

The (2,3) and (2,4) output dimensions match the broadcasted inputs.  That consistent with broadcasting.

`np.dot` is an example of a `numpy` function where broadcasting does not apply.